# Averaging daily observations to a single day across multiple columns, R

Tags: r, group-by

I have an R data frame with multiple observations per day (table 1). There are multiple columns. I would like to summarise each day to an average for each day (for all columns). See table 2. A single number per day for all columns and rows. I have looked at dplyr and group_by, however can only get it to work with a single column (date + 1 column, not date >1 column). Appreciate your assistance.

[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQtZG.png)

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZtj3.png)

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("mood")), mean)`

Comment: Awesome, works a treat, cheers